# Creating a slideshow in jQuery (not images)

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a couple of `div` elements contained in one container `div`, and I would like to slide through them, showing only one at a time, and after a certain timeout slide the currently visible div to the left using an animation, and slide in the next div from the right.

My HTML looks something like this:

```
<div id="topMaps" style="height: 225px; overflow: hidden;">
  <div>First slide - some content here</div>
  <div>Second slide - some content here</div>
  <div>... slide - some content here</div>
  <div>n'th slide - some content here</div>
</div>
```

I'm using the following script for this:

```
var currentSlide = 1;
var numSlides = -1;
var slideSpeed = 1000;
var timePerSlide = 3500;

function nextSlide() {
    $('#topMaps div:nth-child(' + currentSlide + ')').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, slideSpeed);
    currentSlide += 1;
    if (currentSlide >= numSlides)
        currentSlide = 1;
    $('#topMaps div:nth-child(' + currentSlide + ')').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, slideSpeed);

    setTimeout(nextSlide, timePerSlide);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    numSlides = $('#topMaps div').length;
    setTimeout(nextSlide, timePerSlide);
});
```

But it's not working. When the `nextSlide` function is called for the first time, Firefox reports the following error:

```
o.easing[this.options.easing || (o.easing.swing ? "swing" : "linear")] is not a function
http://localhost/templates/front/default/js/jquery.js
Line 19
```

And when I add `$('#topMaps div:nth-child(' + currentSlide + ')')` in the Watch panel in Firebug, it returns a collection of 10 elements? Reall not sure what's going on.

Maybe someone can help me out?

**edit** I figured out the problem with the selector, I needed to use `$('#topMaps>div:nth-child(' + currentSlide + ')')` (notice the `>`). It's still not working though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not the answer you were wanting, have you considered using the [Cycle Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/)?

Comment: I'm using the cycle plugin elsewhere, but this specific slideshow doesn't contain ``<img />`` elements, so that won't work.

Comment: Why not? The Cycle site has examples not using images (Intermediate Demos (Part 2))

Comment: Well I'll be darned! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I might recommend setting an ID for each div and calling it in the nextSlide() js function,test the currentSlide variable and choose the next div
It's not a good programming thingy but you can at least make it work till you figure out what's wrong with $('#topMaps div:nth-child(' + currentSlide + ')')

Comment: I fixed the problem with the selector (check my edit), but still getting the same error.

Comment: could you debug and check where's the error? on hide, show, length or setTimeout?

Comment: ok good, now since you fixed the selector error, you should getting reference to the div right? try this div .hide() only and check if u get the same error

Comment: so that's where your problem is! after a quick look at jQuery hide documentation are you sure about the parameters? it says hide() only takes speed and callback function, use slideUp(slideSpeed) and slideDown(slideSpeed)
anyway its been a long time since i used jQuery maybe im wrong! reply please with the result

Comment: I took it from here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide But what you're saying makes sense with the error message I'm getting... I think. Anyways, I know about slideUp and slideDown, but I'd prefer them to slide to the left.